# Setting up CXF JAX-RS' proxy-based API for converting @FormParam objects to JSON

Tags: java, client-side, cxf, jax-rs

### Quick sum-up of the problem:

I need to somehow configure a JAX-RS client implemented using CXF's [proxy-based client API](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-client-api.html#JAX-RSClientAPI-ProxybasedAPI), to automatically convert parameters annotated with @FormParam to JSON.

---

I have created some services in Apache CXF JAX-RS that takes several potentially complex objects as arguments. By implementing valueOf(String s) for complex beans I can pass several JSON encoded objects to the "method", not just one, as one would normally be the case.

An example implementation could be the following:

```
@Service("receiverService")
@Path("/receiver")
public class ObjectReceiverService {
    @POST
    @Path("jsonTest")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public MyObject jsonTest(@FormParam("myPrimitive") int myPrimitive, @FormParam("myComplex") MyObject myComplex) {
        return myComplex;
    }
        ...//
}

//domain class with Mapper from Jackson
public class MyObject {
    public String foo;
    public String bar;
    public String baz;

    public static MyObject valueOf(String s) throws Exception {
        return new ObjectMapper().readValue(s, MyObject.class);
    }
        ...//implementation of equals() etc.
}
```

This works quite nicely. So far I have tested it by resorting to low-level stuff; manually constructing query strings using Jackson's ObjectMapper etc. Example:

```
//test class with lots of manual setup using WebClient
public class ObjectReceiverServiceTest {
    @Before
    public void setup() {
        ProviderFactory.getSharedInstance().registerUserProvider(new JacksonJsonProvider());
    }
    @org.junit.Test
    public void jsonTest1_recievingSameObject() throws Exception {
        String url = "http://localhost:8080/";
        String path = "rest/receiver/jsonTest";

        MyObject myObjectToSend = new MyObject();
        MyObject result = new MyObject();
        myObjectToSend.foo = "foo";
        myObjectToSend.bar = "bar";
        myObjectToSend.baz = "baz";

        WebClient client = WebClient.create(url);
        client.path(path);
        client.accept("application/json").type(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE);
        Response r = client.post("myPrimitive=123&myComplex=" + new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(myObjectToSend));

        result = new ObjectMapper().readValue(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((InputStream) r.getEntity())).readLine(), MyObject.class);
        assertEquals(myObjectToSend, result);
    }
```

What I would like to do, is to use the proxy based api, [as demonstrated in the CXF docs](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-client-api.html#JAX-RSClientAPI-ProxybasedAPI). This would be far cleaner and faster to implement. The previous test would be something like

```
@org.junit.Test
public void jsonTest2_recievingSameObject() throws Exception {
    String url = "http://localhost:8080/rest";
    ObjectReceiverService service = JAXRSClientFactory.create(url, ObjectReceiverService.class);

    MyObject myObjectToSend = new MyObject();
    myObjectToSend.foo = "foo2";
    myObjectToSend.bar = "bar2";
    myObjectToSend.baz = "baz2";
    MyObject result = service.jsonTest(123,myObjectToSend);

    assertEquals(myObjectToSend, result);
}
```

Today, this throws an WebApplicationException in org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.FormEncodingProvider.writeTo(..), as it is probably just expecting primitives.

I am not quite sure how to deal with this. Any ideas? Is it somehow possible to make an annotation, say @JSONtoString, that would somehow magically replace the objects toString method with a JSON one? As in String toString() { return new ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(this); }

Comment: Not an answer, but additional info from Sergey@CXF mailing list:
(me):
 I am not quite sure how to deal with this. Any ideas? I tried
 overriding toString() with { return new
 ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(this); }, which is ok, but
 FormEncodingProvider.writeTo still fails when trying to convert
 non-string objects,
 like an Integer to String.
--
(sergey:)Yes, it does expect Strings only - I think the fix needs to be applied
at the client side, before FormEncodingProvider is invoked, because
JAX-RS requires the support for MultivaluedMap<String, String> -